# Cannot launch Eclipse form terminal with PATH defined

Tags: command-line, launcher, eclipse, ide

I've installed eclipse by eclipse installer downloaded from eclipse's website, then I've added it's directory adding the following line to my $HOME/.bashrc

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/development/eclipse"
```

But when I try to launch using the command **eclipse** it shows: 
**eclipse was unable to locate its companion shared library**. If I go to eclipse installation folder and double click eclipse launcher it's launch without any troublle

Answer (score 0):

I was using just **~** instead of **/home/username/** and it's gave me the problem.

So, changing from **~** to **/home/myuser/** solved my problem.